# Var Initialization in C#

Tags: c#, initialization, var

I've written a small code that uses an OCR. I've come across a confusing situation where my variables of datatype **var** get initialized before even the code reaches to the point where they're being initialized.
Please have a look at this screenshot 
[image]

the line of code `RecAPIPlus.RecInitPlus(null,null);`is supposed to return status of API initialization. This line hasn't even executed but my status variable seems to have a default value i.e. **REC_OK**  that the above line of code was supposed to return when it executes. 
Can anyone explain the reason of this? Here's the complete code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Nuance.OmniPage.CSDK;
namespace OmniPage
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            try
            {

                Console.WriteLine(Nuance.OmniPage.CSDK.ZONETYPE.WT_AUTO);



                var status=RecAPIPlus.RecInitPlus(null,null);
                IntPtr a;
                var output = RecAPI.kRecLoadImgF(0, "out.txt", out a, 1);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the return type of RecInitPlus ? Does it return an enum? Does this enum have explicit values ? If REC_OK is the first enum member and it has no explicit value, then its value is 0, which is the default. What value did you expect the variable to have before assignment?

Comment: Think of `var` as a placeholder, the compiler will fill it in for you. So it always has a type.

Comment: While you might define the variable at any point in your code the compiler will actually define it at the top of the current scope with a default value.

Comment: It returns an enum @Thomas and REC_OK is the first enum member

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the data type of the `status` field is an `enum`. The first value of the enum is the default value (if the enum is unnumbered, else the `0` value is).

`var` just means "use the data type returned from that method (or assignment in general). So `var` here means just "the enum type returned".

That means that if `REC_OK` is the first value in the enum, it is the default value of that field. Enum's can't have a null value so it shows the default value.

I see the break point didn't come there yet. It still shows the current state of those uninitialed variables in the scope. That is just a Visual Studio thing.

Comment: This doesn't really explain why `var` has become an `enum` value.

Comment: Okay, didn't see that as actual question. Expanded @DavidG

Comment: pretty confusing ("The Visual Studio Thing") but it helped. Thanks @patrick

Answer (score 2):

`status` variable is `Enum` and `enum` is value type, not reference type. Value types always have default values set even though your code has not reached the point were the variable is set. 
Moreover, `var` is not type, it is just syntax sugar and you variable has real `enum` type.

Comment: Have a look at this answer @Patrick , this seems to be the case (+1 for this)